# TinyMCE isn't allowing MVC Controller to receive updated HTML/Text when POST through jQuery "$.post(...)"

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I'm not sure I understand what is happening at the moment.  I have view with information on it that calls a Modal popup, this contains a `TextArea` with a class of `editHtml`, this class will trigger my TinyMCE editor to initiate.

Modal MyView.cshtml:

```
@model x.Models.Content.Elements.ElementHtml

@Html.Partial("_Tools") //This calls the TinyMCE in the next code window

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Edit", "ElementHtmls", 
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "alert('Updated');",
        OnFailure = "alert('Failed');",
        UpdateTargetId = "ElementUpdated_" + Model.Oid.ToString()
    },
    new { id = "ElementForm_" + Model.Oid.ToString() }
))
    {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ElementHtml</h4>
        <p>This: ElementForm_@Model.Oid.ToString()</p>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Oid)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)

        <div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Html, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <div class="col-md-12">

                //This is the editHtml
                //---
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Html, new 
                    { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control edithtml" } }
                )
                //---

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Html, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

JavaScript for TinyMCE:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/tinymce/tinymce.min.js")

<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea.edithtml',
        branding: false,
        height: 250,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
            'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code',
            'code'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code',
        content_css: "/Content/bootstrap.css"
    });
</script>
```

On Save of the Model, I have the following javascript:

```
//...
$(dialog).dialog({
    title: title,
    //...
    buttons: {
        'Save': function () {
            var editForm = $(form);
            if (editForm.valid()) {

                $.post(editForm.attr('action'), editForm.serialize(), function (data) {
                    if (data.Error != undefined && data.Error != '') {
                        console.log("Data error: " + data.Error);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(dialog).dialog('close');
                    }
                });

            }
        },

        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

//...
```

In my code above, I have a Save on the Modal window, this will trigger JQuery's `'Save': function () {`, but also notice that I have a Save button on my cshtml (for testing), this is not what I would like to use, however, note that this Save button does work with the `edithtml` applied.  Not sure if this information helps, both submit to the same Controller.

Everything in the above code sample works properly when `edithtml` is NOT in the @Class, the Controller has the ViewModel, but the property of `Html` is the original value where I want the updated value of course.  Other views with `edithtml` (not being in the Modal) work properly with the TinyMCE applied.

Do I need to tell TinyMCE something during init or customize this section (`$.post(editForm.attr('action'), editForm.serialize(), function (data) {`)?

Any information or feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that TinyMCE is not directly editing the TextArea, adding `tinyMCE.triggerSave();` before doing anything with the form in JavaScript.

First answer with updated code:

```
//...
$(dialog).dialog({
    title: title,
    //...
    buttons: {
        'Save': function () {
            tinyMCE.triggerSave(); // <---- Added this to "save" to the TextArea
            var editForm = $(form);
            if (editForm.valid()) {

                $.post(editForm.attr('action'), editForm.serialize(), function (data) {
                    if (data.Error != undefined && data.Error != '') {
                        console.log("Data error: " + data.Error);
                    }
                    else {
                        $(dialog).dialog('close');
                    }
                });

            }
        },

        'Cancel': function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

//...
```

Second answer, much more automatic...

After taking a step further, I was able to avoid changing the above code and adding a `blur` event to the tinyMCE.init:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    selector: 'textarea.edithtml',
    branding: false,
    height: 250,
    menubar: false,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code',
        'code'
    ],
    toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | code',
    content_css: "/Content/bootstrap.css",

    //Added the following (removing the .log once tested properly)
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
        editor.on('blur', function (e) {
            console.log('Editor was blurred!');
            tinyMCE.triggerSave();
        });
    }

});
```